# OS X 10.11(.1) Randomly freezes while browsing

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

Ever since I updated to El Capitan I keep getting random freezes.. this is the 2nd time it happened while browsing on safari and while watching videos on Youtube. Anyone having problems with this as well? Im on 10.11.1.

I tried resetting the default things, such as PRAM etc. I even brought my MacBook back to the store and there wasn't any hardware issues.

I checked the log and both of the times these freezes happened I see something about watchdog daemon becoming unresponsive. After the freeze, which takes 1 minute or a bit less.. the macbook becomes responsive again but is very very sluggish.

I'm running OS X 10.11.1 on a MacBook Pro 15" 2014.

I could get you log files if needed, not sure which part would be interesting for you but just let me know.

Comment: It would be best to post the log with some entries around that incident. There are too many possibilities at this moment without further information.

Comment: Thans for your reply. The log is huge as hell tho.. I can copy the lines which I think are the start of the freeze.

Comment: According to the Log entries there ist a Report written at "/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/WindowServer_2015-11-15-082423_Clemenss-MacBook-Pro.userspace_watchdog_timeout.spin". Could you post that?

Comment: Yes will do right away.

Comment: I uploaded it too dropbox, you can see the link in the post. I tried pastebin etc but the file is too large.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but take a look at your hard disk SMART status.  You may have a failing drive.  Use this utility (its free for what you need) http://binaryfruit.com/drivedx

Answer (score 1):

I kept having this too. After using Youtube for a while, Safari froze and was then on behaving very sluggishly even if restarted. Only reboot of the whole system restored Browser back to normal (until Youtube would freeze it again).

The problem seems to have disappeared along with the latest OS X 10.11.2, so I recommend you just update the OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Logs i could not see anything useful in identifying your problem. Since your Problem seems to be isolated to Safari and started to appear intermittently after the update to 10.11 i suggest the following actions:

- clear the Safari Cache, f.e. by using the Method described on the following [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204098) at "If Safari doesn't load pages from multiple sites"
- clear the 'Saved Application State' for Safari found at `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState` by deleting the folder (with Safari closed, of course)

Try this first and see if it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. I've cleared the history etc form the first bullet. The 2nd bullet wasn't possible since the com.apple.Safari.savedSate folder wasn't there, perhaps because I cleared everything with the first bulletpoint? I'll let u know if the problem reoccurs. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm back with an update. The crash just happened again. I did some more specific digging and read about a lot of people having problems. The probleem seems to be related to safari and youtube, the crash just happened on youtube as well. So it's definitely related to using youtube on safari and/or flash and safari.